# Request for recommendation: Transition textbook for graduate course in mathematical finance or classical math reference book

Tags: finance, book-recommendation

I am looking for a well-written, theoretically rigorous textbook that contains all the mathematics necessary to transition smoothly to a graduate course in mathematical finance.

I am graduating with a BSc in Economics from a quantitatively rigorous program but continuing my studies in mathematical finance will require a strong mathematical background. While for the program an economics undergrad is formally sufficient it is originally intended for math undergraduates.

I am now looking for a book that ideally would contain everything from highest level pre-undergraduate mathematics up until first year content of a pure mathematics undergraduate degree course; in the subjects of calculus, linear algebra, probability theory, and set theory.

For some of the more fundamental concepts it would be important that they are explored quite formally; I have the impression that the way I learned many of the basic concepts before my undergrad has been somewhat simplistic.

I am looking for the kind of book that is a "classic," that can be referred to to refresh fundamental and intermediate concepts. Something that's in every math students bookshelf.

One suggestion per answer will allow up votes for each recommendation individually.

Comment: I know Thomas' calculus is highly recommended for undergrads and after taking a look at the contents I think it covers more than you would need to know; although it doesn't cover PDEs.

Comment: What I recommend to everyone who asks for things like this though is, look at the individual module pages of undergraduate courses. These module pages will most likely contain a syllabus (so you know what you are expected to know) and they will almost certainly have recommended texts. Moreover there are numerous professors who post their lecture notes online (if you are like me and find someones notes easier and quicker to read).